# How to detect that WPF window has been snapped in Windows 7

Tags: wpf, windows-7

Windows 7 has the snapping feature which 'snaps' a window to the edges, and changes the one dimension of the window size to match the same dimension of the screen, and then choses another size for the other dimension.

I want to detect that it has happened so that in my WindowStyle.None window with custom chrome, I can implement the proper behavior for double clicking the titlebar.

The snapping does not alter the WindowState, so I cannot detect that it has happened. Since only one dimension of window is set to match the the screen, I can not distinquish between a snapped window and a user resized window. Does Win7 send out a specific message, or include a flag in the WM_xxxx messages when it causes a resize? Is the formula to the other dimension (not the one matching the screen) defined anywhere so that I can check if both dimensions match that of a snapped window?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using spy++ to watch window messages to see what gets sent in what order?  maybe there's an extra mesage in there that windows is using.

Comment: Yes. It calls WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, then WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, then WM_MOVE, and finally WM_SIZE. It is the same message flow as a SetWindowPos() call. Also, the WM_SIZE has the type SIZE_RESTORED as the setting. I could capture the resize event and check width and height, but I can only determine the height based on the snap. The width is based on screen size, but I do not not know the formula used.

One other thing I thought about was checking if the height == Screen.Height, and (Left == Top == 0) or (Right == Screen.Right && Top == 0). That seems to give me a 'close enough' scenario.